# how to export a variable from a constant in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I'm currently converting code from Common JS to ES6 and ran into an issue I'm unable to exprort columnset and values variables. Any tips or tricks for this?

```
export const multipleColumnSet = (object) => {
    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
        throw new Error('Invalid input');
    }

    const keys = Object.keys(object);
    const values = Object.values(object);

    columnSet = keys.map(key => `${key} = ?`).join(', ');

    return {
        columnSet,
        values
    }
};
```

However When I try to use it says undefined.

```
import { multipleColumnSet } from '../utils/common.utils.js';
class UserModel {
    tableName = 'user'
    findUser = async (params) => {
        const { columnSet, values } = multipleColumnSet(params)

        const sql = `SELECT * FROM ${this.tableName} WHERE ${columnSet}`

        const result = await query(sql, [...values])

        return result[0]
    }
}
```

I have added the Common JS I've converted from.

```
exports.getPlaceholderStringForArray = (arr) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid input');
    }

    // if is array, we'll clone the arr 
    // and fill the new array with placeholders
    const placeholders = [...arr];
    return placeholders.fill('?').join(', ').trim();
}


exports.multipleColumnSet = (object) => {
    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
        throw new Error('Invalid input');
    }

    const keys = Object.keys(object);
    const values = Object.values(object);

    columnSet = keys.map(key => `${key} = ?`).join(', ');

    return {
        columnSet,
        values
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question but are you sure you're passing in an argument of type object when you call `UserModel.findUser`?

Comment: const user = await userModel.findUser({ email }) I call this in the controller.

Comment: @DMantas what *exactly* does "it says undefined" mean? What is the actual error, and where/when does it happen?

Comment: @DMantas if right under the import you call `console.log(multipleColumnSet({a: "test", b: "test2"})` what is printed in the console?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/423nnkQ

Comment: `columnSet = keys.map(key => \`${key} = ?\`).join(', ');` -> `const columnSet = keys.map(key => \`${key} = ?\`).join(', ');` You have not declared your variable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined

Comment: That's weird why would this happen since it was working fine with common js.

Comment: Modules are evaluated in strict mode and using an undeclared variable is always an error. The CommonJS file was evidently in sloppy mode where *reading* an undeclared variable is an error, *writing* to an undeclared variable is allowed. So, this was always a problem, just not visible before.